# tsql default value dpends on other field

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

is something like that possible ?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_ALERT](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [times] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),
    [times left] [int] DEFAULT(times), --Here times_left get times as default
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T_ALERT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [user_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please don't name your columns with spaces or anything else that requires you to escape the names with square braces.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: You are right - I don't do this normaly but I missed in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can accomplish the same thing by making the column `TimesUsed` (or whatever is appropriate for your usage) and defaulting it to `0`, then just doing subtraction in your query.